# Error - 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

Tags: c, c99, c11

```
[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
[Note] use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
```

I'm giving the above problem's solution, note that I'm using DevC++ code editor here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm giving the above problem's solution, note that I'm using DevC++ code editor here

The above error can be solved by following the steps given below ---

Step 1 - Go to 'Tools'.

Step 2 - Then Click on 'Compiler Options'.

Step 3 - Find 'Settings' tab there.

Step 4 - Under settings tab you'll find 'Code Generation' sub tab.

Step 5 - Now find 'Language Standard(-std)' option.

Step 6 - Click on downward arrow and then select there 'ISO C99' option.

Step 7 - Now click on OK and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the antique tool DevC++ uses a very old version of gcc. Meaning it is unsuitable for study/learning purposes.

All versions prior gcc 5.0.0 (released some ~7 years ago) used `-std=gnu90` as the default setting. Modern versions of gcc use `-std=gnu11` (up to version 10) or `-std=gnu17` (from 10.2.x), which is the lax mode of the modern C11/C17 versions of the standard, also including various GNU C and POSIX extensions.

Unless your major is Software Archaeology, the recommended solution is to update to a better IDE. DevC++ is as far as I know not maintained since forever and it also uses an older branch of the MinGW compiler project (32 bit) also not maintained since forever.

One IDE alternative for Windows is [Codeblocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/), which is free and beginner-friendly, but still advanced enough to also be used for professional purposes. It comes with a fairly recent gcc/mingw version as default.

If you want the latest version of [gcc/mingw64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) for Windows, you can download & install it separately as described here: [How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) I recommend to download the compiled binaries from https://winlibs.com/ since the official Sourceforge link currently contains corrupt binaries.